# Acceder al HREF de un botón que está en otra página web con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen día, me gustaría saber cómo puedo acceder al HREF de un botón de descarga que está en otra página y ese link agregarlo al HREF de mi propio botón.

[Ésta es la página](https://modyolo.com/download/spotify-music-24463/1), que al pasar 5 segundos aparece un botón de descarga:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary px-5 download" href="https://files.modyolo.com/download/WGNPMjZYVUd5eTNreHpKaDQzR2g4cGJBdmRPUGlZUjBpNjE4SXVuSjJxNWJpMW1ZSE5VVTZIczBhK2dJL3Z0bytyK0ZZT2NOc01aSmlnS0t1SjVDR3c9PQ==/Spotify/Spotify%20v8.7.78.373%20[Mod].apk" download=""></a>
```

La idea es que en mi página web, siempre aparezca el link más reciente a ese archivo APK sin tener que modificarlo manualmente cada vez que lo actualicen en la página principal.

Podrían darme una idea de cómo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que no se puede con javascript, porque tiene bloque de iframes y CORS. Deberás hacerlo por backend

Comment: @Yussef entiendo:( como podría hacerlo teniendo en cuenta que estará hosteado como sitio estático en azure y solo puedo usat tecnologías como express?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjbRkt8cew8 Creo que este video puede ayudarte

Comment: Gracias amigo, por la noche le daré una revisada

Comment: Probablemente quieras hacer este proceso desde el lado del servidor o si es del lado del cliente, con software de automatización cómo Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas AJAX para cargar el contenido de la página en la que se encuentra el botón, puedes obtener el HREF del botón después de que se haya cargado el contenido.

En este caso, puedes utilizar la función $.ajax() de jQuery para realizar la solicitud AJAX y obtener el contenido de la página. Una vez que tengas el contenido de la página, puedes utilizar la función $(htmlString) de jQuery para convertir el contenido en un objeto jQuery que puedas manipular y buscar el botón dentro del contenido. Luego, puedes utilizar la función .find() de jQuery para buscar el botón y obtener su HREF.

Por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://tu-pagina-web.com",
  success: function(html) {
    // Convierte el contenido HTML en un objeto jQuery
    var $html = $(html);

    // Busca el botón con la clase "download"
    var $downloadButton = $html.find(".download");

    // Obtiene el HREF del botón
    var downloadUrl = $downloadButton.attr("href");

    // Agrega el HREF al botón de tu propia página
    $("#my-download-button").attr("href", downloadUrl);
  }
});
```

Este código supone que el botón en tu página tiene un ID "my-download-button" y que estás utilizando jQuery para realizar la solicitud AJAX y manipular el contenido de la página. Si no estás utilizando jQuery, puedes utilizar la función fetch() de JavaScript para realizar la solicitud AJAX y utilizar la función document.createElement() y Element.innerHTML para convertir el contenido HTML en un elemento del DOM y buscar el botón dentro del contenido.

En cualquier caso, es importante tener en cuenta que acceder al contenido de otra página web puede violar sus términos de uso y puede ser considerado como una práctica ilegal o inapropiada en algunos casos. Es importante asegurarte de tener permiso para acceder a la página y utilizar su contenido de la manera en que lo estás haciendo.

Comment: ¿De qué manera se captura el botón de la página pasados 5 segundos después de su carga?